# Why can you create a value with "Just (+)"?

Tags: haskell, type-parameter, deriving

Currently I'm learning Haskell and are stuck with the instantiation of types to typeclasses. I actually don't understand, why it's possible to create a value of the `Maybe a` type with `Just (+)`.

The problem why this behaves strange to me is, that the Maybe type is defined as an instance of the `Eq` typeclass (see [Haskell source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Maybe.html#Maybe)) and that if you derive an instance for a type, all the fields of the value / data constructors of that type  must be also an instance of the `Eq` typeclass ([here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#derived-instances)).

With this knowledge in mind, the following code shouldn't be compilable or executable, because a function is not a part of the `Eq` typeclass:

```
let a = Just (+)
let b = Just (-)
```

But GHCi actually executes the code without throwing an error message. If you then try to compare these two values (which shouldn't also be possible) the interpreter comes up with the follwing error message:

```
a == b

<interactive>:24:1: error:
    * No instance for (Eq (Integer -> Integer -> Integer))
        arising from a use of `=='
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    * In the expression: a == b
      In an equation for `it': it = a == b
```

This problem also occurs if you create your own `Maybe a` type.

Comment: Why do you think that `let a = Just (+)` should be an error? It's a value of type `Maybe (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)` -- what's wrong with that? You can't compare `a==b`, sure, but you also can't  compare `(+)==(-)`, yet I think you are OK with `(+)` existing. If `(+)` exists, why should `Just (+)` be forbidden?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The instance of `Eq` for `Maybe` ends up looking like this (that is, `deriving (Eq)` essentially gets rewritten into this):

```
instance (Eq a) => Eq (Maybe a) where
    ...
```

This can be read as **if** `a` is a member of `Eq`, **then** so is `Maybe a`.  So it's perfectly fine to make a `Maybe (Int -> Int)` or what have you, it just won't be `Eq` if its argument isn't.

A more operationally helpful way to think of this, more from the compiler's point of view: to solve a `Eq (Maybe a)` constraint, it suffices to solve the `Eq a` constraint.  So when we say

```
a == b
```

the compiler tries to solve `Eq (Maybe (Integer -> Integer -> Integer))`.  It uses the `Maybe` instance to reduce the question to `Eq (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)`, and then gives up when there is nothing else it can do.  That's why you see the error message complaining about no instance for `Eq (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)` instead of mentioning `Maybe`.